# Dynamic filter in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-mobile

Is it possible to call an API while typing filters in kendo grid or can we add pagination in filters itself.
We have around 5000000 filters,and we are populating data for only 5 filters,If the user wants any other filter,he can type in kendo text box and then we can make api call and show data for all related filters.

I am trying keydown event,but this will close grid and user need to enter again

Sample :

```
$('body').on('keydown', '.k-textbox','#grid' ,function (event) {

        var grid=$('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
         grid.setOptions({
       columns: [{
            field: "ProductName",
            title: "Product Name",
            filterable: {
              mode: "menu,row",
              multi: true, search: true,
              dataSource:
                                            [{ "ProductName": "abc" }, { "ProductName": "bh" }, { "ProductName": "li" }]
    }}]
});
```

Comment: 5000000 filters? What is a filter in your context?

Comment: We have different account names (ranging from 10 to 5000000) associated with a user,and that will be loaded in kendo grid filters when user type , using api call.Initially,we will show only 100 filters.

Comment: @mahan07 FYI, If you want GaloisGirl to see that you have replied to her comment, I suggest you @ her to the start of it.

Comment: @mahan07 I'm not fluent in the Angular version, but I'd go for something along the lines of a [custom filter component](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/reusable-filter/) with a combobox with [server side filtering](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/filtering/#toc-server-side-filtering)

Comment: @GaloisGirl-In combobox,we can select only one value,but the user wants to select multiple values from the drop-down.